# Unable to send data to libwebsocket server

Tags: c, websocket, libwebsockets

I'm trying to write a small plugin for [X-Plane](http://www.x-plane.com/desktop/home/), to create a simple websocket server with [libwebsocket](https://libwebsockets.org/trac/libwebsockets). I'm able to connect to the websocket from Google Chrome, however, when I send data to the server, X-Plane immediately crashes.

I'm pretty certain the [following code](https://gist.github.com/josefvanniekerk/868432986f2f963a5583#file-xplanesocket-c-L185) is causing the problem:

```
unsigned char *buf = (unsigned char*) malloc(LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING + 13 + LWS_SEND_BUFFER_POST_PADDING);
buf = (unsigned char*) "Hello World!";
libwebsocket_write(wsi, buf, len, LWS_WRITE_TEXT);
free(buf);
```

I'm not a C programmer / specialist at all, but does the above seem to have a problem at all?

I've posted the full source on Gist: https://gist.github.com/josefvanniekerk/868432986f2f963a5583

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With any sane interface, @iharob would be right - to be clear he/she *is*
 right about you misunderstanding string assignment.

However, libwebsockets is a bit 'special'. You need to copy the string into the `malloc()`'d array `LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING` bytes in. libwebsockets then overwrites the preceding bytes.

So you want something like (assuming you are not trying to send the terminating zero on the string):

```
char *text = "Hello World!";
int len = strlen (text);
unsigned char *buf = malloc(LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING + len + LWS_SEND_BUFFER_POST_PADDING);
/* copy string but not terminating NUL */
memcpy (buf + LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING, text, len );
libwebsocket_write(wsi, buf + LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING, len, LWS_WRITE_TEXT);
free(buf);
```

If you want to send the `NUL` as well:

```
char *text = "Hello World!";
int len = strlen (text) + 1;
unsigned char *buf = malloc(LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING + len + LWS_SEND_BUFFER_POST_PADDING);
/* copy string including terminating NUL */
memcpy (buf + LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING, text, len );
libwebsocket_write(wsi, buf + LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING, len, LWS_WRITE_TEXT);
free(buf);
```

Comment: Perfect, I pasted your code, and it worked 100% out of the box. Thanks so much @iharob

Comment: Oh, and about "string assignment misunderstanding", you're 100% correct there, I'm not a seasoned C dev, I'm spoilt with other languages like PHP and JS.

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the string, assignment doesn't work as you expect.

Instead of

```
buf = (unsigned char *)"Hello World";
```

you need

```
memcpy(buf, "Hello World", 1 + strlen("Hello World"));
```

when you do the assignment, you make `buf` point to a static string literal, and `free()` is not possible in this case.

Your program invokes undefined behavior because of that.

You need to include `<string.h>`

Comment: I'm afraid you are not quite right there @iharob. libwebsockets is weird. You need to give it a buffer where it is guaranteed it can write to the prepadding. See my answer.

Comment: This `unsigned char *buf = (unsigned char*) malloc(LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING + 13 + LWS_SEND_BUFFER_POST_PADDING);
buf = (unsigned char*) "Hello World!";` is wrong it doesn't matter what! But I see your point.

Comment: At the least, the memcpy() is not causing X-Plane to crash anymore, a tiny bit of progress. Not getting the right data on the browser however, although, getting some kind of response from the websocket server now. Maybe this is where the "special" bit of libwebsocket comes in.

Comment: Yes. I've made it clear in my answer that what you wrote is right re string assignment, but doesn't quite overcome the weirdness of libwebsockets. On the other hand, libwebsockets does actually work ...