# Libwebsockets 2.1.0 - It's illegal to do an lws_write outside of

Tags: c, libwebsockets

I'm using [libwebsockets-2.1.0](https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets/releases/tag/v2.1.0) with `generic session` & `lwsws` option **enabled**.

In `case LWS_CALLBACK_SERVER_WRITEABLE` I've got some code that **opens** a file, and output the content to websocket.

```
static const char* filename = "/tmp/loop.log";
#define MAX_STAT_LINE_LENGTH    256

unsigned char buf[LWS_PRE + 512];
unsigned char *p = &buf[LWS_PRE];

char line[MAX_STAT_LINE_LENGTH];

while ( fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL) {
    int n = lws_snprintf((char *)p, sizeof(line), "%s", line);
    int m = lws_write(wsi, p, n, LWS_WRITE_TEXT);

    if (m < n) {
        printf("websocket write failed\n");
    }
}
```

In the terminal I'm getting a bunch of these:

```
lwsws[13778]: ****** 0x9230a50: Sending new 46 (/name?ag=z&abcd=011), pending truncated ...
It's illegal to do an lws_write outside of the writable callback: fix your code
```

Is there an explanation for this error? I mean, I have declared `char line[1000]` but it's still complaining.

I would like to point out that the **final** output of the websocket is inconsistent, sometimes it stops at `line 30-something`, sometimes it stops at `line 400`

FWIW, the total line of the file I'm reading is **1758** lines, with the longest character length of a line is **107** characters long.

Removing the `fgets` loop and replacing the value with my own generic value seems to work fine.

Thanks

Comment: You should add the declaration of your variables

Comment: what about wsi?

Comment: @Mansuro I believe wsi is a struct of lws, in the function it's declared like:

static int callback_stats_streamer(struct lws *wsi, enum lws_callback_reasons reason, void *user, void *in, size_t len)
{
// my codes here
}

I hope that helped.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/28309837/612920

Comment: @Mansuro Thanks, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to increase the `rx buf` size.

```
#define LWS_PLUGIN_PROTOCOL_DUMB_INCREMENT \
{ 
    "protocol_dumb_increment", \
    callback_dumb_increment, \
    sizeof(struct per_session_data__dumb_increment), \
    4000, /* rx buf size must be >= permessage-deflate rx size */ \
}
```

Source: [libwebsocket's github issue page](https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets/issues/458)